# Removing the Window titlebar after adding content [Android]

Tags: java, android, android-webview

The question is quite simple "How do I remove the titlebar from a WebView, after adding content ? Normally you use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` But you can only use that method before adding content :(

So any ideas ? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the answer to the question is "you can't".

Your best bet is probably turn off the real window title (as you detail in your question) then define a titlebar-like element of your own in your layout file...which you can then show/hide at will.